# Detect if SQL Server connection is over a VPN

Tags: c#, sql-server, network-programming

I need to detect if a connection to a SQL Server database, 2012 or higher, is connecting to a database over a VPN and not to a database within the local area network. In short, I want to work out is the connection is over a WAN or LAN.

Is there something that I can query in the general environment using C# code to do this? I know quite a lot about SQL Server from a development and structure view point but not too good on networks.

For more information, I have a client application and I want to prevent people from connecting to a remote SQL Server database. I have no control over the actual database server so I need to detect if it sis remote and throw up a dialog box.

Comment: You could check the operating system's routing table, see which route handles the IP of the SQL server, and then see which network interface services that route.

Comment: so the VPN might not be on the current computer? it might be handled by a router?